# Unrecognized arguments in tensorflowjs converter

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I am using tf_saved_model to save the model

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(session, checkpoint)
```

following [tutorial](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/import-saved-model.html). 
But something wrong when I tried to convert model to tensorflowjs model

with tensorflow version

```
tensorflowjs_converter -v

tensorflowjs 1.1.2

Dependency versions:
  keras 2.2.4-tf
  tensorflow 2.0.0-dev20190606

and related things
tensorflow                       1.13.1              
tensorflow-estimator             1.13.0              
tensorflow-estimator-2.0-preview 1.14.0.dev2019060600
tensorflow-hub                   0.3.0               
tensorflowjs                     1.1.2
```

I tried

```
tensorflowjs_converter \
     --input_format=tf_saved_model \
     --output_node_names='embedding, contextual-lstm, attention-lstm, projection' \
     --saved_model_tags=serve \
     /model \
     /web_model
```

result:
`TensorFlow.js model converters.: error: unrecognized arguments: /model /web_model`

And another question, what argument `output_node_names` really mean?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `./`, you should change `/model` to `./model`